# Eject kill hot reload (React)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server

I create my app with CRA & eject it, but after start I see this:

```
> [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...

> The development server has disconnected.
Refresh the page if necessary.
```

In my dev-tools. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's ghost-bug) Try to check your webpack.config.js or reload webpack & waiting log "Starting development server"